# How to auto-adjust the size of a Form to fit the size of the controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, picturebox

let's say (for the sake of simplicity) that I have and event that when fired, calls

```
pictureBox1.Size = new Size(500, pictureBox1.Size.Height);
```

The problem is that although the control gets bigger, the main Form1 won't resize... (so I only see just a part of the control that is inside the main Form)
(Note: dunno if important, but the picturebox is anchored)

I tried playing with the AutoSize and AutoSizeMode properties, but it didn't work.
Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Setting AutoSize = True is sufficient.  If you put the PB on another control, like a Panel, then you'll need to allow that container to grow as well.  If you anchored on Right and/or Bottom then you need to turn that off temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first disable the picture-box anchor, then resize the form (by changing its size properties I suppose), and then re-enable the anchors.

Or the better solution is that since the picture-box is anchored within the form, then you can only resize the form, and expect the anchor would result in the resizing of the picture-box as well.

Comment: @Novellizator if you manually resize the form in run-time, does the picture box resize as well?

Comment: well yeah, they both resize - the only problem is that it the part of a picturebox is still outside the window no matter how much i resize the window. It seems that it resized other elements, just not the right one :)

Comment: @Novellizator I've tried to replicate your problem. Resizing the form instead of the picture-box resized the picture-box as well. Since you are changing the width, could you please make sure the picture-box has both right and left anchors, and just change the `Size` of the form instead of that of picture-box in your code.

Comment: ok, seems that it works. So in the end, when I want to change the size of the form according to the change of size of a picturebox, I only need to change the size of the form. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) and [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) properties

Comment: not sure what do you mean - I dont want to dock the picturebox to the specific side of a Form. It is on the right, but I won't take the WHOLE right side (there are more controls here)